# Installing i3 broke MATE? “Your session lasted less than 10 seconds”

Tags: linux-mint, i3, mate-desktop

I’ve just installed i3 and after using it for around 10 minutes (and not being able to open anything using dmenu — nothing loaded), I tried going back to MATE. I’m running Mint 18.2 Sonya.

I get the following errors:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...

/etc/mdm/Xsession: 27: /home/bthalenberg/.profile: [[:  not found

localuser:bthalenberg being added to access control list
```

Everything seems to work from tty, I even tried removing i3 but it did not fix the issue. I’m posting from my phone, sorry for the crappy formatting

Comment: Fixing your `.profile` to run without error on `/bin/sh`, which on Debian and derivatives such as Mint is not `bash`, will either work or get you a more useful error message. Single `[` is a command, double `[[` is a `bash` extension